# Is the powerset of the real numbers well orderable?

Tags: well-orders

I know that $\mathbb N$ is well orderable and $\mathscr{P}(\mathbb N)$ (the real numbers) are well orderable, so I was wondering if $\mathscr{P}(\mathscr{P}(\mathbb N))$ is also well orderable. I tried thinking about the elements as vectors so that I could order them by magnitude or direction, but of course, some vectors have the same magnitude and/or direction. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How can you ask if something is well ordered if you haven’t equipped it with an order? Anyhow it is wellorderable.

Comment: I'm not sure you've asked what you intend to here. Assuming the axiom of choice $\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is well-order**able** (it doesn't make sense to say that a set is well-order**ed**, to use that term properly we need to specify an ordering), and indeed so is every set including $\mathscr{P}(\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N}))$. In set theory without choice, $\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})$ itself isn't guaranteed to be well-orderable.

Comment: @MathGeek If you drop the axiom of choice, then even the initial claim that $\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is well-orderable isn't justified.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Why not? The definition of a well orderable set is a set that satistfies anti-symmetry, transitivity, totality and that a  finite subset of the set has a smallest element.  The set of real numbers satisfies all four of those conditions.

Comment: @MathGeek First of all, that's **not** the definition of "well-ordered" - that's the definition of "**linearly** (or **totally**) ordered." You need to drop the word "finite." Second, a set can be ordered in multiple different ways: $\mathbb{N}$ with the usual ordering is well-ordered, but with the opposite of the usual ordering is not well-ordered. You need to specify an ordering in order to say "order**ed**" instead of "order**able**."

Comment: @NoahSchweber Okay, so what about if we allow all subsets, not just finite?

Comment: That said, at this point I think I know what question you're trying to ask, namely: "Is it consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ that $\mathscr{P}(\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N}))$ cannot be linearly ordered?" This is a nontrivial question, and the answer is in fact **yes**. In particular, it's consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ that there is a amorphous set of sets of reals, and no amorphous set can be linearly ordered.

Comment: @MathGeek "Okay, so what about if we allow all subsets, not just finite?" In that case we're back to my original comment: you can't prove in $\mathsf{ZF}$ that $\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is well-orderable. Certainly the usual ordering on $\mathbb{R}$, which is in easy bijection with $\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})$, is not a well-ordering (consider e.g. $(0,1)$, or even $\mathbb{R}$ itself or $\emptyset$).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thank you for your time Mr. Schweber. I think you should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there are a few confusions here.

First of all, both **well-orderedness** and **linearly-orderedness** are properties of sets *equipped with specific orders*. It doesn't really make sense to say "$\mathbb{N}$ is well-ordered," for example; what we should say is "$\mathbb{N}$ *with the usual ordering* is well-ordered."

Second, and more substantively, there is a difference between well- and linearly-orderedness. In a linear order every (nonempty) finite set has a minimum since all elements are comparable; the defining property of a well-order, however, is that **every** subset has a least element.

This, then, is the complete situation:

- In $\mathsf{ZFC}$, every set is well-order**able**, although of course not all linear orders are well-orders.
- In $\mathsf{ZF}$ (= set theory without choice), we can prove that $\mathbb{N}$ is well-orderable (using the usual ordering) and $\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is *linearly* orderable (by bijecting with $\mathbb{R}$ and using the usual ordering on the latter).
- However, it is consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ that $\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is not well-orderable. It is also consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ that $\mathscr{P}(\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N}))$ is not even linearly orderable. Interestingly, these situations are related: in $\mathsf{ZF}$ we can prove that if $A$ is well-orderable then $\mathscr{P}(A)$ is linearly orderable (think about the phrase "least point of difference").

These issues have been discussed at various points on this site and MO; see e.g. [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37272/are-all-sets-totally-ordered).